# How do use JSON body in REST requests?

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and Phils RESTserver. I know how to send the request body in normal Form format but how can I send it as a JSON object instead?

I do this now:

```
lastname=bond
```

I want to do this instead:

```
{"lastname" : "bond"}
```

I tried to just replace the Content type header from:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In to this:

```
application/json
```

This did not do anything. Codeigniter says the POST array is empty.

Comment: why do you need to send via JSON, can't you just `json_encode` the post on the server?

Comment: I need to try using JSON objects because I cannot send special characters using POST querystrings. This does not work: lastname=åsbrrg

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to create a request that contains a JSON node inside the request body. Assuming this, I think it's not possible to create such a request using simple HTML form tags as your browser always will try to pack your input vars in a querystring like format.
You will need JavaScript to achive this (I think all popular libs like Scriptacoulous or JQuery comes with helper methods for this).

Comment: I need to try using JSON objects because I cannot send special characters using POST querystrings. This does not work: lastname=åsberg